# Set a background image for a webview in Android

Tags: android, background, webview

I want to set a background image for a webview in android.
I did the following:

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backgroundImage);
```

I want the image to be in the middle of the webview. Any help please?

**EDIT**
I have found the solution:

```
linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backgroundImage);
linearLayout.addView(imageView);
frameLayout.addView(linearLayout);
frameLayout.addView(webView);
```

Answer (score 1):

This below normally works for me -

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
myWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

Comment: I am getting the desired background for the webview, but it fits all the view. I want it to be just centered.

Comment: What do you mean by centred - like a gradient which starts from the top and finishes in the centre or only in a certain area?

Comment: I am not sure how that can be done but can suggest you to create an image of the size of the screen and then edit in gimp or something to color it wherever you need it and then use this image as a background of your webview

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this , first create  a html page like

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<img src="2.png"width="320" height="480" /> 
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

and then load the url page

```
public class Activity1
extends Activity {
WebView Webview1;


@Override    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.filegolfrule);
Webview1 = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);

   webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    Webview1.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/a.html");


}

}
```

Comment: The user obviously wants to set a specific background for the webview loaded locally from assets that he will then load other content in. This answer does not help the user find what they're looking for.