# android css background-image not found

Tags: android, css

I'm trying to use a image texture for my webpage body background. My webpage is shown in an Android webview.

Here is my CSS :

```
body
{
    font-family: helvetica;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #555555;
    padding: 10px;
    /*background-color:#000000;*/
    background-image:url(bg_header_sample.png);
}
```

the css is inside an HTML file named `Template.html`. both `Template.html` and `bg_header_sample.png` are in the same assets folder : `assets/global`.

If I un-comment the `background-color:#000000;` line my body turn to black as wanted.

but with the current CSS my body stay transparent ...

Comment: have you tried to add a background-position? Does your browser load your png?

Comment: I'll tried a background-position. I think my browser is not loading the png, but I'm not sur and I don't know why ...

Comment: I'm using a webview in Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to do it programmatically :

```
webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backgroundImage);
```

As explain in this question :
[Set a background image for a webview in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280406/set-a-background-image-for-a-webview-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

try putting the file name in quotes

```
background-image:url('bg_header_sample.png');
```

Comment: depending where the css is called from, maybe you need the path to the file; `background-image:url('assets/global/bg_header_sample.png');` or maybe `background-image:url('/assets/global/bg_header_sample.png');`