# Css background images not loaded in webview android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, css

Guys I am trying to load a web url , everything works fine except loading background images

I have read this page

[android css background-image not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826208/android-css-background-image-not-found)

but my question is different , I don't want a background for page body . I need to show background image for a div

HTML :

```
<a href="#WomenMonth"><li data-menuanchor="firstPage" class="manavatarchoose"> test </li> </a>
```

CSS :

```
.manavatarchoose{
width:206px;
height:206px;float:left;
background-image: url("http://www.example.com/demo/android_connect/assets/img/maleorfe.jpg") ; border-radius:150px;    list-style-type: none; vertical-align:middle; 
}
```

and this is my java class

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com/demo/android_connect/get_webmob.php");
    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

I also used absolute path to images in css file.

I should mention that the html page is correct in browser but when loaded inside app images and some of the stylesheet attributes does not show up .

Answer (score 0):

CSS is supported in Webview since Android 3.0. So make sure your device is above Android 3.0. CSS animations are supported by Android devices above 3.0 — but only if a single property is changed. As soon as you try to animate more than one property at once, the entire element disappears. In non-native Android browsers, the element will be visible for the duration of the animation, but will hide immediately after it’s finished. This is fixed in Android 4.4 Kitkat. Kitkat uses Chromium (same engine as in Google Chrome) which supports CSS3 and HTML5 completely. You could also use a different method to use CSS in webview with WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL:

```
htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\"      type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />" + htmlData;
```

// lets assume we have /assets/style.css file
    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", htmlData, "text/html",   "UTF-8", null);
And only after that WebView will be able to find and use css-files from the assets directory.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks , I added this :  String htmlData = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\"      type=\"text/css\" href=\"style.css\" />";
  WebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.example.com/webmob.php",htmlData, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
   but it says Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method loadDataWithBaseURL(String, String, String, String, String) from the type WebView

Comment: I found the sollution here: https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/133598/solution-for-those-with-the-android--webview--resource-images-not-showing-problems . Hope this helps,