# Can i set background image in a webview?

Tags: android, webview

I want to set background image in a webview in android , so that whenever no page or url is load , it shows a background image in a webview.

Comment: What you had tried so far to achieve this?

Comment: Coulod u please check this, might this helpful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280406/set-a-background-image-for-a-webview-in-android?rq=1

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set background image in a webview by adding that line of code :

```
webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_name);
webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000);
```

Comment: Use `android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT` instead of `0x00000000` for readability but otherwise this solved my problem!

Answer (score 2):

```
webView.setBackgroundColor(0x00000000); //<-- Color to transparent
webView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backgroundImage);
```

Comment: Use `android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT` instead of `0x00000000` for readability but otherwise this solved my problem!